# Why is Word's spelling checker flagging contractions and correctly-spelled words?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm using Microsoft Word for Mac 2011.

The spell checker is flagging all kinds of weird stuff as shown below...

[image]

("didn" as part of "didn't" is flagged.)

[image]

("couldn" as part of "couldn't" is flagged.)

Here's an example of the dialog that appears if I right-click a flagged word and choose `Spelling...`

[image]

Any idea why it says "Spelling: Dutch" or why it thinks "alone" is misspelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is probably as the others have said. Assuming that is the case...

In Mac Word 2011 the main option is the Language... option in the Tools menu.

You need to select the text that you want to mark as English, then select the correct version of English in the dialog and uncheck "Do not check spelling or grammar". You can select the entire body text using cmd-A.

I would also check that when you create new blank documents and start typing, Word marks the text with the correct language. If it does not, you will need to find and open the normal.dotm template, apply the correct language to its body text, and save it. Normal.dotm is typically at

Macintosh HD:Users:username:Library:Application Support:Microsoft:Office:User Templates:normal.dotm"

Where "username" is your Mac user name. The Library folder does not appear in the Finder in recent versions of Mac OSX, but in Finder, click the Go menu, then hold down the Option key (alt key) to reveal the folder name.

Answer (score 1):

It says:`Spelling: Dutch` because Dutch is the current language you have selected in word. The word Dutch will be replaced by whatever language is selected, and in my case that is `English (Australia)` as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

You can change the language by clicking the `Dutch` button the at the bottom of the screen, which will look similar to this:

[image]

Your Word is flagging correctly spelled English words, but misspelled Dutch words.

Answer (score 0):

Its simply a change in the language setting of MS Word. Your language setting is currently Dutch and I believe 'Alone' and 'proceeded' are not Dutch words. Hence the spell check flag.

Simply change the language back to English. In Word 2007 for Windows, its located in the 'Review' tab. You should also find the language setting when you right-click on the marked words.